# PHP preg_replace to insert string into input string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a string in format:

```
Rooms available: Master bedroomDining roomLiving room
```

I want to convert this string into like:

```
Rooms available: Master bedroom, Dining room, Living room
```

So, inserting a ', ' (comma and space) in between each lowercase_char[here]UPPERCASE_CHAR

Getting the lowercase_charUPPERCASE_CHAR is easy but can't figure out how to insert ', ' in between them.

Anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a regex, you need to put the each letter in its own capture group, so you can split them apart.

```
$string = 'Rooms available: Master bedroomDining roomLiving room';

$string = preg_replace('/([a-z])([A-Z])/', '$1, $2', $string);
```

DEMO: https://regex101.com/r/vQ6hP7/1